# What references to Sombra exist in the game now?

Tags: overwatch

Sombra is being teased quite heavily as the next hero for Overwatch, and I know that there are some easter eggs hidden in some maps and voice lines.

For example, Reaper will sometimes say "Where is Sombra when you need her?" and on a few maps, there are pictures and news clippings of her.

What are the currently known references to her existence within the Overwatch universe?

Comment: I think this question could be improved if you included some evidence of why you think this is the case. Otherwise you risk the question being closed due to speculation. You might find some evidence on the Overwatch Gamepedia. http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra

Comment: Some more thoughts too, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtZKsae55EU&feature=youtu.be&a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is an interaction in which Reaper says "Where is Sombra when you need her?"
- There is a [picture](https://abload.de/img/sombra_who_isqiqhh.jpg) of a newspaper in Dorado. The Spanish phrase translates to "Who is Sombra (or Shadow)?"
- A [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX7CR.jpg) of some classified files, including Soldier: 76, Jack Morrison (who's now Soldier: 76), and Sombra.
- On the third point in Dorado, there are [security terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhNFO.jpg) that say "UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS. PROTOCOL SOMBRA."

These are the references in-game. A lot of more information can be found at this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4n1ugz/everything_we_know_about_sombra_so_far/) which I used as reference for this answer.

Comment: Don't forget [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CmsjJH1UMAEcsVT.jpg:large) and its [Spanish counterpart](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cmsra3dWIAANceq.jpg), which adds the name A. Amari. While not specifically mentioning Sombra, it is widely believed that she is, in fact, this support sniper.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't forget, it's definitely on the link I put there. However OP's question was "what references to sombra exist in game" so I only mentioned the ones in the game, not outside of it.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little slow on editing my comment, but it's never really mentioned that the sniper is Sombra herself, and the "in game" point is valid.

Comment: That should be "its Portuguese counterpart" I am fairly certain. That is from the Brazilian Overwatch account on Twitter. Also, it looks like Portuguese to me.

Comment: It's definitely portuguese, but it's the same thing on the spanish one (A.Amari also shows there). Blizzard probably reviewed and editted it out on the US version afraid of giving too much information, but didn't update the translations.

Answer (score 0):

If Pharah gets a direct kill with her missile Launcher and S.76 is nearby, he may say "You must've got that from your mom." While it's not a direct reference to Sombra, there is lots of speculation that Sombra is Pharah's mother, and it's confirmed that Pharah's mom fought alongside Soldier 76 in the defense of Overwatch HQ. She was presumed dead, but then again, so was Reaper and S.76.

Comment: As it turns out, Pharah's mom is a different character, [Ana](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/ana/), who was announced earlier today.